# Given a MySQL datediff, how to output the actual date range in use

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following MySQL query which shows me the # of new users grouped by week.

This is the query:

```
SELECT  floor(datediff(u.created_at, curdate()) / 7) AS weeks_ago,
        count(DISTINCT u.id) AS "New Users in Week"
FROM users u 
GROUP BY weeks_ago
ORDER BY weeks_ago DESC;
```

This outputs:

```
weeks_ago | New Users in Week
0 | 100
1 | 120
2 | 50
```

How can I add a column that shows the date range, for example, if ran today (2019/07/16)

```
weeks_ago | date range | New Users in Week
0 | 2019/07/14 - 2019/07/20 | 100
1 | 2019/07/7 - 2019/07/13  | 120
2 | 2019/06/30 - 2019/07/6 | 50
.....
```

Comment: Not an answer - but: You can use `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK, u.created_at, curdate()) as  weeks_ago`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about two columns with the minimum and maximum date?

```
SELECT floor(datediff(u.created_at, curdate()) / 7) AS weeks_ago,
       date(min(u.created_at)), date(max(u.created_at))
       count(DISTINCT u.id) AS "New Users in Week"
FROM users u 
GROUP BY weeks_ago
ORDER BY weeks_ago DESC;
```